# Finding $g'(x)$ given $g(x)=\int^{e^x}_1 \ln(t)dt$ without integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration

A friend of mine told me I would have to use integration by parts to use $g(x)=\int^{e^x}_1 \ln(t)dt$ to solve $g'(x)$, but I am a Calculus 1 student, and integration by parts isn't used until Calculus 2. So I feel like there must be a way to figure out what $g'(x)$ is without using that.

Could somebody help me out?

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: I have read both parts, but I am not sure how to apply them to this. According to part 1 If $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then the function $g(x)$ defined by $g(x)=\int^x_a f(t)dt \;\;\;\;\;\; a \le x \le b $ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $g'(x)=f(x)$

Comment: $g(x)=\int_b^{p(x)} T(t) dt$ means $g'(x)=T(p(x))$ assuming all the restrictions are met.

Comment: @randomgirl The way I read your comment, it seems like if $g(x) =\int_a^b f(x)dx$ then $g'(x)=f(b)$ but $\ln(e^x)$ is apparently not the right answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189082/derivative-of-an-integral-function-with-variable-bound-that-appears-in-integrand/3189086#3189086

Comment: You can simplify that @LuminousNutria

Comment: oops and I did forget the times p'(x) thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people have already given answers to this question, but to give some clarifying remarks, we define the function $h(x)$ by $$h(x) = \int_1^x \ln(t) \; dt.$$ In particular, we have $$h'(x) = \ln(x)$$ by the First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Then note that $g(x) = h(e^x)$, so by the Chain Rule, $$g'(x) = \frac{d}{d(e^x)} h(e^x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} e^x = \ln(e^x) \cdot e^x = xe^x.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$g(x) = \int_1^{e^x} \ln (t) \, dt=h(e^x)$$

where $h(s) = \int_1^s \ln (t) \, dt$.

$$g'(x) = h'(e^x) \frac{d}{dx}e^x = \ln (e^x) \cdot e^x = x\cdot e^x$$

Answer (score 2):

$g(x)=f(h(x))$ where $h(x)=e^x$ and $f(x)=\int_1^xln(t)dt$. $g'(x)=f'(h(x))h'(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$\;ln x\;$ is a continuous function in all its domain of definition, and thus it has a primitive function $\;F\;$ (in every closed bounded  interval of its domain, but this is a really too much now), meaning: $\;F'(x)=\ln x\;$ for any $\;x\in(0,\infty)\;$ , thus by the FTC:

$$g(x)=\int_1^{e^x} \ln t\,dt=F(e^x)-F(1)\implies g'(x)=\left(F(e^x)\right)'$$

and now apply the first part above and the Chain Rule...

Comment: I think you meant : $ (F(e^x))' $, not $ F'(e^x) $?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to apply the chain rule to the *First Fundamental theorem uf Integral Calculus*:
$$\left(\int_1^y f(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)'=f(y)$$
with $y=\mathrm e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

let $ t = e^u$, then $ \ln t = u$,$ dt = e^u \ du$,

$$g(x) = \int_1^{e^x} \ln t \ dt = \int_0^x u e^u \ du$$

then $g'(x) = xe^x$